# d3js - the last `appended` element alone applied the style property

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I have 6 data's in my array. But in the document I have only 5 `p` elements. so I decided to create a new `p` element.

after applying the style, once the last created element alone applied. bore the 5 `p` element has no style applied.

I am wrong to handle the 'enter`and`exit` here i guess. any one help me to sort this please?

here is mycode :

```
$(function () {

var datas = [
  {"font":15,"color":"green"},
  {"font":18,"color":"blue"},
  {"font":24,"color":"yellow"},
  {"font":36,"color":"orange"},
  {"font":42,"color":"brown"},
  {"font":54,"color":"gray"}
];

  d3.selectAll('p')
    .data(datas)
    .enter().append('p') //it is only getting the style applied
    .text(function(d) { return d.color; })
    .style('font-size', function (d, i){
      return d.font + 'px';
    })
    .style('color', function (d, i){
      return d.color;
    });


})
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/6WvGL9yZKvMyO7O9Ywfa?p=preview)

Comment: See e.g. [this tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not have been any `p` DOM and you should call the script after page load (so that the data gets linked to the appended `p DOM` ).

Something like this to ensure the body is loaded and then the script is executed.

```
  <body>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sQ3hXA9RbQFUDzMX0y5E?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

Issue 1:

You must always call the script function after the DOM is loaded.
In your fiddle you load script.js in the head.

Issue 2:

This will add data and create new p DOMs and associate data to the already existing p DOMs.

```
selectDIV.selectAll('p')
    .data(datas)
    .enter()
    .append('p')
    .text("tello");
```

This will update all the p DOM whether present already or created.

```
selectDIV.selectAll("p").style('color', function(d,i){
  return d.color
})
```

Corrected fiddle [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1gW1Fm7eSxMkXezXPKjq?p=preview)

Comment: a additional question, why i am not able to generate `p` tags here: http://plnkr.co/edit/6WvGL9yZKvMyO7O9Ywfa?p=preview